# TLSv1.2 with SHA1?

Tags: ssl, encryption, sha256

I'm sure there is an easy answer for this, but how am I using TLSv1.2 with non-TLSv1.2 cipher suites? For example [this link](https://login.salesforce.com/) shows that the connection is using TLS 1.2, but is using AES_256_CBC_SHA ? I thought that all TLSv1.2 had to be SHA256 or higher?

And, [paypal home](https://www.paypal.com/home) shows "Connection uses TLS 1.2", but the cipher selected is RSA_128_RC4_SHA ???

Am I missing something? (All info using google chrome)

Can't post a screenchot of my capture because I don't have at least 10 reputation??? WTF

Answer (score 6):

TLS 1.2 still supports all ciphers earlier SSL/TLS version defined, which includes insecure ciphers using RC4, all the EXPORT ciphers etc. But it also defines some new ciphers, like GCM ciphers and various ciphers using SHA384 as HMAC.

> I thought that all TLSv1.2 had to be SHA256 or higher

No and you probably confuse this with deprecating SHA-1 as a *signature* algorithm for certificates. This deprecation is independent from TLS itself although certificates are usually used in connection with TLS. And use of SHA-1 or even MD5 as a HMAC for ciphers is still considered safe, because the security assumptions needed for HMAC and certificate signature are different.

Apart from that a better forum for these kind of questions would be security.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at Chrome's output, it should say that `SHA1` is being used for message authentication, which is not actually part of the cipher.  A quick search of the Googles reveals that `SHA1` is still an acceptable `MAC` for TLSv1.2: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Data_integrity